# Getting IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR with keycloak running on AWS ECS cluster when doing SS0 authentication with Microsoft

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-active-directory, keycloak, amazon-ecs, microsoft-identity-platform

I integrated microsoft as an identity provider with keycloak running on ecs cluster.
Getting below error while doing sso authentication with it
[image]

Below are the server error.

`[0m05:11:09,785 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990 [0m[33m05:12:22,201 WARN  [org.keycloak.connections.httpclient.DefaultHttpClientFactory] (default task-8) TruststoreProvider is disabled [0m[31m05:12:22,772 ERROR [org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (default task-8) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1598) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1426) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1324) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:411) at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436) at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384) at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@13.0.1//org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp.makeRequest(SimpleHttp.java:277) at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@13.0.1//org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp.asResponse(SimpleHttp.java:216) at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@13.0.1//org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp.asString(SimpleHttp.java:208) at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.1//org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider$Endpoint.authResponse(AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider.java:500) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:546) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:435) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:396) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:398) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:365) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:150) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:110) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:141) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:104) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:245) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:61) at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129) at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@13.0.1//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:41) at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.1//org.keycloak.services.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filter(AbstractRequestFilter.java:43) at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@13.0.1//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.doFilter(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:39) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78) at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61) at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52) at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99) at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387) at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841) at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35) at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990) at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486) at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377) at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.4.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:483) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:110) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1418) ... 96 more [0m[33m05:12:22,873 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-8) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=security-admin-console, userId=null, ipAddress="", error=identity_provider_login_failure, code_id=53df7fd3-4305-45fe, authSessionParentId=53df7fd3-4305-45fe-ba58, authSessionTabId=P5gL601`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't looks like a problem of the Keycloak, but problem of your AWS infrastructure setup.

Make sure your ECS task has proper internet connectivity (security group, subnet ACL, NAT, internet gateway, ...), because Keycloak needs to exchange code for the token with Microsoft.